# How to save images which are picked from gallery?

Tags: java, android, image

I am selecting multiple images from gallery and when we are clearing recent apps the images which we selected also getting deleted. I want to display the images even though it is removed from recent apps which means I want to save the image in app.Please provide me code of it.
You can see a screenshot here for more clarification:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aYPI.png)

By click on the image I can pick image from gallery and after click on below button I want to save it in application.

Here is my **main activity.java**

```
package com.amazoneindia.imageupload;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView iv1,iv2,iv3,iv4,iv5;
    Button btn;
    private final int CODE_IMG_GALLERY1=1;
    private final int CODE_IMG_GALLERY2=2;
    private final int CODE_IMG_GALLERY3=3;
    private final int CODE_IMG_GALLERY4=4;
    private final int CODE_IMG_GALLERY5=5;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

         init();


         iv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(new Intent().
                        setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).
                        setType("image/*"),"Select image"),
                        CODE_IMG_GALLERY1);
             }
         });
         iv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(new Intent().
                                 setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).
                                 setType("image/*"),"Select image"),
                         CODE_IMG_GALLERY2);
             }
         });
         iv3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(new Intent().
                                 setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).
                                 setType("image/*"),"Select image"),
                         CODE_IMG_GALLERY3);
             }
         });
         iv4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(new Intent().
                                 setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).
                                 setType("image/*"),"Select image"),
                         CODE_IMG_GALLERY4);
             }
         });
         iv5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(new Intent().
                                 setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).
                                 setType("image/*"),"Select image"),
                         CODE_IMG_GALLERY5);
             }
         });

    }

    private void init(){
        this.iv1=findViewById(R.id.D1ivss1);
        this.iv2=findViewById(R.id.D1ivss2);
        this.iv3=findViewById(R.id.D1ivss3);
        this.iv4=findViewById(R.id.D1ivss4);
        this.iv5=findViewById(R.id.D1ivss5);
        this.btn=findViewById(R.id.btn);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode==CODE_IMG_GALLERY1&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Uri imageUri=data.getData();
            if (imageUri!=null){
                iv1.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }
        }
        if (requestCode==CODE_IMG_GALLERY2&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Uri imageUri2=data.getData();
            if (imageUri2!=null){
                iv2.setImageURI(imageUri2);
            }
        }
        if (requestCode==CODE_IMG_GALLERY3&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Uri imageUri3=data.getData();
            if (imageUri3!=null){
                iv3.setImageURI(imageUri3);
            }
        }
        if (requestCode==CODE_IMG_GALLERY4&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Uri imageUri4=data.getData();
            if (imageUri4!=null){
                iv4.setImageURI(imageUri4);
            }
        }
        if (requestCode==CODE_IMG_GALLERY5&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Uri imageUri5=data.getData();
            if (imageUri5!=null){
                iv5.setImageURI(imageUri5);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us the approach which you are thinking and maybe we can help further you on this. Simply asking for code will not help you to learn.

Comment: Actually i used firebase database for upload the images but at the time of retrieving the images , all images shown same .. Then i checked  my database i saw all the url are also same i dont know why either im uploading different images. Thats the main problem

Comment: Soo what you can do is store the selected images URI in local db and when user starts your app again then check if you have any valid entries. Then directly display images in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem is that you are not saving your image url anywhere and when you remove your app from recent the variables also get cleared so solution is that you can save it in **SharedPreferences** and get it any time anywhere in your code.
**Note** clearing the app data from setting will also clear data from sharedPreferences.
Follow this link
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java

Comment: Thanks Lucky for providing the answer

Comment: my pleasure dear